# iText7 Not Detecting Spaces in PDF Reader

Tags: itext7

I have the following code to read a PDF:

```cs
static string ReadPDF(string fileName)
{
    PdfReader pdfRead = new PdfReader(fileName);
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfRead);

    ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();

    StringBuilder processed = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); i++)
    {
        var page = pdfDoc.GetPage(i);
        string text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, strategy);
        processed.Append(text);
    }

    return processed.ToString();
}
```

I have processed several resumes with it and sometime PDFs it will recognize the spaces and others it will just combine all the text. Both those that were properly processed and those that weren't use the same fonts and formatting (at least to the visible eye).

What could be the cause for this? Is it an issue with how users may have created the PDFs (like if they converted it with word vs acrobat).

Comment: Spaces separating words in a PDF can be created in two ways, either a space character is drawn or the text insertion point is moved forward a bit. The latter mechanism can also be used for kerning, i.e. not for separating words. Thus, text extraction in case of use of that mechanism needs to use heuristics to tell whether a word separation is there or not. Such heuristics can fail. If they fail for you very often, you may want to share example documents for which we can tweak the heuristics.